How to use iOS .framework files in .NET 8.0 MAUI
Can someone please create a binding library that uses .framework and NOT ".a" static lib along with working MAUI demo that uses the binding library so we can close this issue and get it over with?

Step 1:
Create a folder structure like this:
App/ (.NET 8.0, MAUI)
│   App.csproj
│   ...
App.Binding/ (iOS/MacCatalyst Binding Library)
│   ApiDefinition.cs
│   App.Binding.csproj
│   StructsAndEnums.cs
App.Frameworks/ (created by hand)
└───FAT
└───Frameworks

Step 2:
Copy the .framework(s) into the App.Frameworks/FAT/ and App.Frameworks/Frameworks/ directory
Step 3:
Generate a FAT framework from the frameworks. Note that you can add more than one framework into the FAT framework, as long as they are targeting different architectures
lipo -create -output App.Frameworks/FAT/[Name].framework/[Name] App.Frameworks/Frameworks/[Name].framework/[Name] ...

Step 4:
Use Sharpie to generate the ApiDefinition.cs and StructsAndEnums.cs.
Notes:

You might need to run this command with elevated permissions (e. g. sudo) if you are using Apple frameworks as imports
You might need to change the paths of the imports in the header files to relative paths, e. g. #import <MyFramework/MyFrameworkExt.h> to #import "MyFrameworkExt.h" (in this case both headers would be in the same directory)
This example is for iOS, but should be similar for MacCatalyst

sharpie bind --sdk=iphoneos16.2 --output="ApiDefinition" --namespace="App.Binding" --scope="App.Frameworks/FAT/[Name].framework/Headers/" "App.Frameworks/FAT/[Name].framework/Headers/[Name].h"

Step 5:
Copy the parts of the newly generated files, found in the directory ApiDefinitions, which you will need for your bindings into the following files:

App.Binding/ApiDefinition.cs
App.Binding/EnumsAndStructs.cs

Step 6:
Remove any [Verify] attribute from the files in the binding, since they will be causing errors and remove the using directive at the very top of the App.Bindings/ApiDefinition.cs file, which refers to the framework you are linking
Step 7:
Notes:

If you are using MacCatalyst you need to modify the location paths in the linker flags
Check which frameworks you are using in the <Frameworks> tag and change them to your needs

Update your App.Binding/App.Binding.csproj by adding the following:
<ItemGroup>
    <NativeReference Include="..\Frameworks\FAT\[Name].framework">
        <Kind>Framework</Kind>
        <Frameworks>Foundation UIKit [Name]</Frameworks>
        <LinkerFlags>-L "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator/" -L "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos" -Wl,-rpath -Wl,@executable_path/Frameworks</LinkerFlags>
    </NativeReference>
</ItemGroup>

Step 8:
Update your App/App.csproj file to load the binding project.
Notes:

You might consider adding a conditional loading of the reference
Even though you are linking the project reference, some IDEs require to build the binding by hand and then unload the binding project in order to display code completion and accept the using directive in other files

<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\App.Binding\App.Binding.csproj"/>
</ItemGroup>


Hopefully this will help you and I did not miss out on any step.
If you have any questions, just let me know!
BR,
Niko

"some IDEs require to build the binding by hand and then unload the binding project in order to display code completion and accept the using directive in other files" I think we are seeing this. The Binding library is building and I can see the public types via Object Browser but they cannot compiled against and the Using statement does not work. In Xamarin Forms we only referenced the DLL. Are you saying reference the CSPROJ instead?

That is how I got it working. Reference the .csproj, build it by hand, unload the binding project while still referencing the .csproj. Sounds weird, but it seems like the design-time-build is not including the generated binding sources.

When you say "build it by hand" do you mean from the command line or right clicking on the specfic project in Solution Explorer and clicking "Rebuild"?

UPDATE. That's crazy. I just built the CSPROJ (as you said) then unloaded it and it worked?????

Usually I just use the context menu of the project and select build/rebuild. So you got it working? :D

Yes but it feels so fragile. Many many thanks for your help. You really went out of your way. Much appreciated

I does not feel right, but in the end within a normal build it is exactly the same. It's just a design-time-issue. Hopefully it will be fixed soon. And of course, anytime!
